# react native bottum tab icon absolute issue

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, react-navigation-bottom-tab

I am want to float my home icon above the tab bar but it gets cut can someone suggest how to do that.. aim also attaching the screenshot and navigation stack structure

```
stack navigation
  -1. drawer nav
     -a. Tab nav
```

[image]

```
            position: 'absolute',
            bottom: 20,
            height: 58,
            width: 58,
            borderRadius: 58,
            backgroundColor: colors.primaryColor,
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center',
            shadowColor: '#000',
            shadowOffset: {
              width: 0,
              height: 3,
            },
            shadowOpacity: 0.29,
            shadowRadius: 4.65,
            elevation: 7,

            flex: 1,
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to play with the **zIndex** property of each of the component ?
or maybe the **overflow** property ?
... hard to say without having a look at the code structure.

Another solution would be to build a component for the button you want to overlap.

Comment: Just to be more specific, I would suggest to add a zindex: 0 in the parent component and a zindex:1 in the child. Once again, the solution could be different depending on the way you structured the code.